# Ruby - Move element of array to given position

Tags: arrays, ruby, sorting, element

So effectively I'd like to move a given element of an array, by referencing a specific location via a conditional argument passed into the method.

For example if I had an array of

`array = [a, b, c, d, f, g]`

And created a method along the lines of this with a key value pair as a conditional

`def move_element(a, right_of: d)`

`end`

Is this possible with a given array method within Ruby? If so I'm not familiar with it.

Cheers in advance

Comment: You need to edit to make `a`, `b`,... Ruby objects. Assuming they are to be strings you need to put them in quotes.

Comment: There is no element `a` which is to the right of an element `d` in your example, so it is completely unclear what you expect the result to be. Also, you only say that you want to "move the element", but you never say where you want to move it to. Please, make sure you provide a clear, precise, unambiguous, complete, objective specification of what you want to achieve, including any and all rules, exceptions, special cases, corner cases, and edge cases. Also, please provide example inputs and outputs of all of those in the form of *valid* Ruby code.

Comment: When asking a question, you will get better results if your sample code is valid. Try putting your code in a file and running it.

Answer (score 4):

We are given:

```
arr = ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'f', 'g']
```

Initially I assume you wish to modify (mutate) `arr` (rather than create a new array and leave `arr` undisturbed). Later I construct a method that does not mutate `arr`.

Let's first constuct a method that takes as arguments the index of the element to be moved, the index of the element it is to follow and, of course, the array:

```
def move_position(arr, n1, right_of:)
  arr.insert(right_of, arr.delete_at(n1))
end
```

Try it.

```
move_position(arr, 1, right_of: 3)
  #=> ["a", "c", "d", "b", "f", "g"]
```

```
arr = ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'f', 'g']
move_position(arr, 0, right_of: 3)
  #=> ["b", "c", "d", "a", "f", "g"]
```

```
arr = ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'f', 'g']
move_position(arr, 0, right_of: 5)
  #=> ["b", "c", "d", "f", "g", "a"]
```

```
arr = ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'f', 'g']
move_position(arr, 0, right_of: 0)
  #=> ["a", "b", "c", "d", "f", "g"]
```

See [Array#index](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.7.0/Array.html#method-i-insert). Note that `arr.index(i,o)` inserts `o` *before* the element at index `i`, but since

```
a = arr.delete_at(n1)
```

is executed before

```
arr.insert(right_of, a)
```

`o` is inserted *after* the element originally at index `i`.

Note that `right_of:` in

```
def move_position(arr, n1, right_of:)
```

specifies that the value of `:right_of` is a *required* variable (no default value, as when `right_of: 3` is used). *Named parameters* (or *arguments*) were introduced in Ruby v2.0. The syntax for making a named parameter required was added in Ruby v2.1.

---

Now create a method that replaces the two indices with the elements found at those indices. This only works, of course, when the two elements involved are unique in the array.

```
def move_element(arr, e1, right_of:)
  move_position(arr, arr.index(e1), right_of: arr.index(right_of))
end
```

This this method.

```
arr = ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'f', 'g']
move_element(arr, 'b', right_of: 'd')
  #=> ["a", "c", "d", "b", "f", "g"]
```

```
arr = ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'f', 'g']
move_element(arr, 'a', right_of: 'd')
  #=> ["b", "c", "d", "a", "f", "g"]
```

```
arr = ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'f', 'g']
move_element(arr, 'a', right_of: 'g')
  #=> ["b", "c", "d", "f", "g", "a"]
```

```
arr = ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'f', 'g']
move_element(arr, 'a', right_of: 'a')
  #=> ["a", "b", "c", "d", "f", "g"]
```

---

If you do not wish to mutate `arr` you can write the following:

```
def move_position(arr, n1, right_of:)
  arr.each_index.map do |i|
    case i
    when 0..n1-1, (right_of+1)..arr.size-1
      arr[i]
    when n1..right_of-1
      arr[i+1]
    when right_of
      arr[n1]
    end
  end
end
```

```
arr = ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'f', 'g']
```

```
move_position(arr, 1, right_of: 3)
  #=> ["a", "c", "d", "b", "f", "g"] 
move_position(arr, 0, right_of: 3)
  #=> ["b", "c", "d", "a", "f", "g"]
move_position(arr, 0, right_of: 5)
  #=> ["b", "c", "d", "f", "g", "a"] 
move_position(arr, 0, right_of: 0)
  #=> ["a", "b", "c", "d", "f", "g"]
```

Confirm `arr` has not been mutated:

```
arr
  #=> ["a", "b", "c", "d", "f", "g"]
```

`move_element` is unchanged:

```
move_element(arr, 'b', right_of: 'd')
  #=> ["a", "c", "d", "b", "f", "g"] 
move_element(arr, 'a', right_of: 'd')
  #=> ["b", "c", "d", "a", "f", "g"] 
move_element(arr, 'a', right_of: 'g')
  #=> ["b", "c", "d", "f", "g", "a"] 
move_element(arr, 'a', right_of: 'a')
  #=> ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'f', 'g']
```

```
arr
  #=> ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'f', 'g']
```